# what is the best way startup AEM server

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

what is the best way startup AEM server in an production environment:

is it from the crx-quickstart\bin\start

or

through the jar file. What are the essential parameters needed.
I have created a script like this:

set CQFOLDER=C:\AEM6
java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=30303 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx1024m -Dorg.apache.sling.commons.log.level=INFO -jar cq6-author-p4502.jar -p 4502 -verbose -nofork

Another thing is: can I start AEM through jar and still set my runmode in sling.properties(after the first installation) .

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, your best bet is likely to start it as a Windows service.  Check out this article for full details on how this is done:
http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/getting_started/download_and_startworking.html#Installing%20and%20Starting%20Adobe%20Experience%20Manager%20as%20a%20Windows%20Service

Also documented at http://aemtips.blogspot.com/2013/10/installing-and-starting-adobe.html

Otherwise, you will likely want to run it from the command line.  This link has the essential parameters: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/getting_started/download_and_startworking.html#Starting%20Adobe%20Experience%20Manager%20from%20the%20Command%20Line

This link talks to options for setting run modes and which ones take precedence: http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/configure_runmodes.html#Starting%20CQ%20with%20a%20specific%20run%20mode

Answer (score 0):

If you start your author AEM instance from crx-quickstart\bin\start . You wont be able to debug your java code.

Run the below command on AEM-author folder to run AEM in debug mode.It will help you to debug the java code in eclipse.

*java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=30303 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -Xmx1024m -Dorg.apache.sling.commons.log.level=INFO -jar cq5-author-p4502.jar -p 4502 -verbose -nofork*

Comment: Why would you enable the debugger in a production environment?

Comment: <i>Its not required for production environment . Just i told how to debug in local .  </i> @toniedwiesz

Comment: The OP is asking about production deployments specifically.